# Hover and active page styling

Tags: css, hover

I'm attempting to make my anchor text white when a person hovers over a nav item or when the nav item page is active.

Currently, all is well except the text color. Sounds simple enough but I'm struggling.

I'd like the anchor text to become white when the nav item is either hovered over or is the active page. Currently the anchor text just turns grey, I suspect due to the opacity thats on there too.

Here is the code that I have been using:

```
.dropdown ul li.current_page_item,
.dropdown ul li:hover,
.dropdown ul li.on {
    background-color: orange;
    opacity:0.4;
    color: white;   
}
```

It could be that this is not the relevant sample of code but I cannot see what else could be important here. I'm working on a Wordpress site and am finding working with the CSS a little tricky. Here is the site itself if anyone thinks I've not added the relevant snippet: http://tinyurl.com/m562wgd

Comment: have you tried `color: white !important;` ?

Comment: !importat in a sign that you don't understand CSS specificity. fail.

Comment: In general: style the A-tag for menus, not the LI.

Comment: I thought we fixed this yesterday?

Comment: @PaulRadich yes we did I wondered if you'd notice. In fiddling with the CSS elsewhere I somehow lost the styling from yesterday. Given the large number of edits I made I'd have a hard time pin pointing exactly what I did to negate yesterdays input. I've gone down a rabbit hole in styling with this WP site (sorta defeats the purpose of WP). I think I'm good now though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anchor tag does not inherit the color from its parent, so you should set it explicitly:

```
.dropdown ul li:hover a{
    color: white;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `color: white;` from your `.dropdown ul li.on` rule and instead add it to this new css rule:

```
.dropdown ul li:hover > a {
   color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the css to hyperlink inside the li tag

```
.dropdown ul li a:hover {color: white;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right that it's the opacity that's making the text appear gray. The way you have the code you are applying a 40% opacity to the white text. If you truly want white, either drop the opacity completely or make it a higher value (0.9).

Not sure why you want the opacity, but keep in mind that not all browsers recognize opacity - and show the 100% white. And I believe IE8 and lower do not support the :hover psuedo-class on anything but an  tag.

```
.dropdown ul li.current_page_item a,
.dropdown ul li a:hover,
.dropdown ul li.on a {
    background-color: orange;
    opacity:0.4;
    color: white;   
}
```

Hope this helps.